# Setting up PlasticSCM for Students

Tags: unreal-engine4, plasticscm

So I am an educator and a novice at using version control software. I am currently trying to set up a Repository for my students that will allow them to use PlasticSCM to collaborate with eachother on a Unreal Engine project. I am looking to use the main account I set up in the cloud to manage their project while teaching them the basics of Version Control workflow.

I am having issues with figuring out what the best method to loop them into the repository that I set up? should I just create new accounts for each of them and add them in or is there a better method?

Comment: I would suggest using Perforce for unreal4, due the the integration and binary file support. It is very easy to break a project folder(Mostly map and texture references.) UE5 has the single object per file option, minimizing the impact.

Answer (score 0):

> should I just create new accounts for each of them and add them in or
> is there a better method?

Yes, you can ask your students to create an account and you can invite them to your Organization to access the same repositories, be aware of the limitations of the free cloud version to handle the repositories for all your students (5Gb for free and up to 3 active users).

About integrations, plastic has a [Unreal Engine Plugin](https://github.com/PlasticSCM/UE4PlasticPlugin#readme) and also has binary file support.

A [new version 1.6.2 of the Plastic SCM plugin for Unreal Engine 5](https://github.com/PlasticSCM/UEPlasticPlugin/releases/tag/1.6.2), with additional polish to the support of Changelists (new UI/UX features of UE5) has been released, the plugin is in continuous improvement and maintenance!